# Tornado main IOLoop takes 20s to process new request despite ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, tornado

I have some heavy computation that needs to be done upon receiving a request without blocking the main IOLoop. To achieve that goal, I'm using ProcessPoolExecutor in a coroutine:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from random import uniform
import uuid
import time
from datetime import datetime
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

def worker_function(msg):
        start = time.time()
        count = 0
        seed = 1
        while count < 99999999:
                seed = uniform(1.1,1.2)
                count += 1
        end = time.time()
        msg['seed'] = seed
        msg['local_time'] = end - start
        return msg

class EventHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

        def initialize(self):
                self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

        @tornado.gen.coroutine
        def get(self):
                print "Received request at %s" % datetime.now()
                result = yield self.executor.submit(
                        worker_function, {'id':str(uuid.uuid1())}
                )
                self.write(result)
                self.finish()
                print "Finished processing at %s" % datetime.now()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        counter = {'count':0}
        application = tornado.web.Application([
                (r"/test", EventHandler),
        ])
        application.listen(8888)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

To test the correct behavior, I'm loading the url in two separate browser's tab at around 1 second delay. Here is what the script outputs:

```
Received request at 2015-09-09 23:58:00.899278
Received request at 2015-09-09 23:58:23.329648
Finished processing at 2015-09-09 23:58:44.530322
Finished processing at 2015-09-09 23:59:05.120466
```

The two process are indeed running in parallel and I can see two CPU cores being used at 100% in htop. The problem is the 20 seconds delay between the two "Received request".

How can I make sure that the main IOLoop stays snappy?

Ps: The script is running on a Linux VM with 2 CPU cores.

Comment: Exactly what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I'm using python 2.7.6.

Comment: Note that the problem does not seem to occur if I query the url from a python script that fires up some requests.get() calls. I can reproduce this only in my browser.

Comment: I could not reproduce it in the browser using Python 3.4 (having only changed the `print` statement). Besides that I have Python 2.7.10 but it does not seem to have `concurrent.futures`. Any packages you installed for that? Anyway you might want to pay some attention to your testing methods.

Comment: I've installed futures (pip install futures) as mentioned in the documentation. What do you mean by paying attention to my testing methods?

Comment: I tested with 2.7.10 under OS X and had no troubles at all. I don't have access to 2.7.6 or a Linux machine (with your particular configuration and so on). What I'm saying is that you nee to make sure that there are no other factors outside of Python that cause this behavior or worse, only make it look like this is the behavior when in fact it works correctly. Also, I see a lot of imports here that don't do anything in this sample code. Did you test the exact code you show here in isolation as well (without the rest of the program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're testing with a browser, and browsers don't like to request the same url twice at the same time even if it's in two different tabs (they wait for the first request to finish before starting the second to see if they get a cacheable response). Add some unique query parameter to each url and you should see both tabs proceed in parallel (or test with two different browsers instead of two tabs in the same browser).

Also, your ProcessPoolExecutor should be a global (or a member of your Application) instead of a member of your RequestHandler. All requests should share the same executor.

Comment: Indeed chrome is the problem here, it works fine with two browsers or a threaded python script. Thanks for the tip concerning ProcessPoolExecutor that should be a global!